# compare variable value with part of IP

Tags: bash

I have several IP addresses that I want to list it based on internal or external IP: our internal IP for example start with 10.10.10.X, I was thinking about writing bash script to do this job for me, I tried to use the script below to read all IPs from text file.

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
IP=$(echo "$line" | cut -c1-8)
if [[ "$IP" == '10.10.10' ]]; then
echo " $line" >> /tmp/internal.txt
else
echo " $line" >> /tmp/external.txt
fi
done < "$1"
```

but I faced the following problem (when debugging the code) when variable IP compared with 10.10.10 it will be shown as

```
[[ X.X.X. == \1\0\.\1\0\.\1\0 ]]
```

and the result always will be external, please advise what I did wrong.

Edit with example:

Let us say `/tmp/ip.txt` I have the following IPs.

```
10.10.10.1
192.168.5.1
20.30.5.1
```

After checking the IPs both `192.168.5.1` and `20.30.5.1` should go to `/tmp/deny.txt` and `10.10.10.1` should go to `/tmp/allow.txt`

Comment: not an answer to your question, but shouldn't `-c1-8` be `-c1-9`?

Comment: my bad copied the old compare, while I was trying to fix it. removed an extra .

Comment: @don_crissti yes

Comment: @don_crissti thanks found my solution by comparing variables, inset of IPs. that did the trick for me